# Taylor coefficients for $f(x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to proove that the Taylor coefficients of $f(x^2)$ at $x_o=0$ are

$a_{2k}=\frac{(2k)!}{k!}$

and

$a_{2k+1}=0$

How can I do this? I cannot use power series. Nevertheless I don't know that the function is analytic. Is there an inductive basic way to show this. $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think you must assume that the Maclaurin series of $f$ exists, from this information you must define the Maclaurin series of $f(x^2)$

Comment: yes but how to define the Maclaurin series of $f(x^2)$?

Comment: Observe that $[f(x^2)]'=f'(x^2)2x$ and $[f(x^2)]''=2f'(x^2)+4x^2f''(x^2)$, etcetera.